# How to get a return value when a given session variable is or isn't null

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, session-variables, asp.net-4.0

I use the following dedicated class to manage session variables in my applications (ignore misspelled names; that's intentional):

This first code block is for usage. You can see the class it is calling on, at the next code block

```c#
//'importing' the class for current project
using SeSn = Debug_Tests.Seseions.SeSn;

// creating an object (usually with name related to currentProject)
public static SeSn.CreatCurrentSesionVariablsStructNamed CurSesVarStruct = new Seseions.SeSn.CreatCurrentSesionVariablsStructNamed();

// the long name helps me in this little 'chaos'
```

This is an instance of a `struct`, that is 'grouping' or 'tying' all my `globals` into one bundle. Whenever I may need to store my global variables, I will assign the values into the appropriate-struct-variable that `CurSesVarStruct` has to offer.

Then all I need is to access session variables once, only to extract the "Variable-collection" -`object`, ... as it is actually a session variable that I keep its name constant - `_CurrentSesionGlobals`.

In short, it's the struct that is stored in the session as one of the session variables - data type = `object`, or you could say a clone of the struct to be saved between sessions.

Since I have that and can use it with `_CurrentSesionGlobals`, I could just access any value I need from session through the following, for example:

**Assign the struct before storing it in `Session`:**

```C#
CurSesVarStruct.SelectedUercustid = custID;
```

Then the next method  - `ExtrctSesnVar()` below, allows me to use for example:

**Extract a variable that was saved in last session:**

```C#
custID = ExtractSesnVar().SelectedUercustid;
```

So `SelectedUercustid` is actually one of the struct members.

#### **The Question/Problem**

Performing extraction of `_CurrentSesionGlobals` out of the session variables.

```C#
public static SeSn.CreatCurrentSesionVariablsStructNamed ExtrctSesnVar()
{
    var CurrAppGlobals = SeSn.GetValueAS.ACloneOfTheStructObj("_CurrentSesionGlobals");
    return (SeSn.CreatCurrentSesionVariablsStructNamed)CurrAppGlobals;
  //the question is refereing this location.
}
```

How can I have a **return value** for a `null` result, or a condition that will first ask if the `object` / a given `Session Variable`, that I am trying to extract isn't `null`, or does not exist?

Currently there's an *exception error* while I am trying to get the value of a non-existing session variable.

The next code block is a class that I add into the solution, as a helper to every website application. It's actually a namespace, so the class that is responsible to handle session variables is `Sesn`:

```
namespace Seseions {
    public class Sesn {
        public static bool isNotEmpty() {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys.Count > 0;
        }
        public struct CreatCurrentSesionVariablsStructNamed {

            // some of commonly used variables- still testing options..

            public int ManagerCustID;
            public int SelectedUercustid;
            public int recordID;
            public int SelectedMonth;
            public int SelectedChosenWorker;
            public int SelectedYear ;

            
            public string SelectedTable;
            public string SelectedColumn;
            public string SqlSelectCommandLastQuery;
            public string TableOfUsersReference;
            public List<string> Fontlist { get; set; }

        }

        // converts and extract values of session variables

        public class GetValueAS {
            public static CreatCurrentSesionVariablsStructNamed ACloneOfTheStructObj(string currntProjectSesVarStructName) {
                if(HttpContext.Current.Session[currntProjectSesVarStructName] != null) {
                    return (CreatCurrentSesionVariablsStructNamed)HttpContext.Current.Session[currntProjectSesVarStructName]; 
            }

            public static int _Int(string SesParameterValToReturn) {
                return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session[SesParameterValToReturn]);
            }

            public static string _String(string SesParameterValToReturn) {
                return Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session[SesParameterValToReturn]);
            }
            public static DataSet _DataSet(string SesParameterValToReturn) {
                return (DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Session[SesParameterValToReturn];
            }
            public static DataTable _DataTable(string SesParameterValToReturn) {
                return (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session[SesParameterValToReturn];
            }
            public static bool _Bool(string SeSnVarToCheckOn) {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SeSnVarToCheckOn] == null)
                    return false;
                return (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session[SeSnVarToCheckOn];
            }
        }

        // an easy way to access and mange session variables actions
      public enum Act {
          Add, Remove, Replace
      }

      public static void Modify(Act action, string New_SesnVarName= null, object NewP_Value=null, string Currnt_Ses_SesnVarName=null) {
          switch (action) {
              case Act.Remove:
                  if (isNotEmpty()) {
                      HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(CurSes_ParamName);
                  }
                  break;
              case Act.Replace:
                  HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(CurSes_ParamName);
                  HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(New_SesnVarName, NewP_Value);
                  break;

              case Act.Add:
                  HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(NewQs_SesnVarName, NewP_Value);
                  break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but on MSDN you can find a lot of useful information on session state in ASP.NET - a good starting point is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx).

Comment: @Yahia could you understand the issue of the question, that i now stuck without a solution for?. : a variable that is actually a struct that is stored in session context. i need to retreive it and avoid the exeption, did i have to make sure to ask for it only when i know that it's there (if asked for it only on page postbacks) , i think what i really need for now it the solution to assign the *live* global variable without an exeption if the object in session i tried accessing was not there this is the exeption if you did want 2 know *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* thank

Comment: I understand what you say BUT I don't understand why you are doing this ? why a `struct` and not `class` ? why are implementing your own global object when ASP.NET comes with some good options built-in (see the link provided) which are ready to use and well-tested ?

Comment: i think it's a new exeption not related to the one i had before (still trying varius options).as you could understand if you are asking for the object which does not exist you must supply an alternative return as the condition with bolean - if its true , return true if its false return false. here i am asking with no alternatives as the only return type could be my Type ... the struct

Comment: Aside: your identifier names are migraine-inducing. If it's your house style, fine, but for SO questions it's better to avoid abbreviations and run things through a spellchecker. (Capitals and punctuation wouldn't hurt either.) If you want to prevent ambiguity with the framework classes, use some sort of prefix instead.

Comment: @millimoose i will sure take that in to consideration !, I actually do (translate / convert / correct ) namings when passed here as a question (usually)...but i Will ..be more aware of this issue, from now on... Mr. moose(; also the prefixing part,thanks for commenting on that , by the way , i've posted a new question (before reviewing your comment though) i'm sure you could help (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't do this.

- critical: do not put Session (user) related data in static variables. It is not thread-safe.
- best practice: try to avoid `static` in ASP.NET for everything else too.
- best practice: do not use `struct`s for anything but small, immutable and identity-less types

It seems you are over-engineering this. All you need (for now) is to use some constants for the strings:

```
public static class SessionKeys
{
   public const string ManagerCustID = "ManagerCustID";
   ...
}
```

and then you can start focusing on code that adds value to your app.

Comment: thanks for the tips, it is going to be used **this instant**, gonna move to public non static modifier, and my struct into a class, and at all..., i am going to reconstruct the *globals* whole idea of "session-state-storage" procedure , and re *engineer* it (don't treat this as a renegade act on original ready made tools as i am trying to learn about it too) so that is also for my common programming capabilities as an exercise too, so that way i am trying to come up with my own ideas as solutions to problems i meet in the way then checking how did i come close and how it differs from Designer